# python pandas sorting by group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table

Each row in my DataFrame is a user vote entry for a restaurant. The data look like

```
id   cuisine    
91   american   
3    american   
91   american   
233  cuban      
233  cuban      
2    cuban
```

where `id` refers to the restaurant.

I want to get something like the following

```
american  91   100
          3    30
          12   10
cuban     233  80
          2    33
mexican   22   99
          8    98
          21   82
```

where the 2nd column is the `id`, and the 3rd column is the number of rows in the DataFrame for that `id`.  In other words, sort by the number of rows, but group by cuisine. I tried

```
g = df.groupby(['cuisine', 'id'])
c = g.size().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

But the order of the cuisines is mixed.

Comment: Please post an example DataFrame.

Comment: take a look at pivot tables : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `value_counts` after `group_by` followed by `sort_index`

```
# ascending=[1, 0] says True for level[0], False for level[1]
df.groupby('cuisine').id.value_counts().sort_index(ascending=[1, 0])

cuisine   id 
american  91     2
          3      1
cuban     233    2
          2      1
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

Comment: The `value_counts()` is sorted in descending order by default. Even the final sort can be saved!

Answer (score 2):

is that what you want?

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
    id   cuisine
0   91  american
1    3  american
2   91  american
3  233     cuban
4  233     cuban
5    2     cuban

In [3]: df.groupby(['cuisine', 'id']).size()
Out[3]:
cuisine   id
american  3      1
          91     2
cuban     2      1
          233    2
dtype: int64
```

or as a data frame:

```
In [10]: df.groupby(['cuisine', 'id']).size().reset_index(name='count').sort_values(['cuisine', 'count'], ascending=[1,0])
Out[10]:
    cuisine   id  count
1  american   91      2
0  american    3      1
3     cuban  233      2
2     cuban    2      1
```

Comment: Sorry my example was too simple. On my real data, if I do what you suggested, then the count within the cuisine is not sorted.

Comment: @nos, i've updated my answer - please check. Please provide a [reproducible sample and desired data sets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) in future

Comment: @nos, please check [piRSquared's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38464909/5741205) - it's much better